# Adding a filter to image before drawing on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to add a css filter before I draw the image on my canvas. This is my javascript.

```
    img = new Image();
    img.src = "picture.png";
    img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
    img.style="filter: saturate(8);";

    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.lineJoin = "round";
    context.lineWidth = cursorSize;
    img.onload = function() {
        context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.drawImage(this, 0,0,width,height);
        layer.draw();
    };
```

If I load this image into anything other than the canvas it renders, correctly. But I'm not seeing the saturated image on my canvas. Am I missing something? Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The CSS filter sits on top of the image element and isn't a part of the image itself, so when drawn to canvas only the bitmap is used.

Fortunately, there is now support in some browsers for CSS filters for the context itself. Simply move down the line for CSS filter on the image to the context like this (with reduced code for sake of clarity):

```
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    context.filter = "saturate(8)";            // use CSS filter here
    context.drawImage(this, 0, 0, width, height);
    context.filter = "none";                   // reset filter
};
img.src = "picture.png";
```

Note: not supported in all browsers which in case the filter must be applied manually and from scratch.

Comment: Is there a way to set the filter after the image is drawn?

Comment: @AlexKonetchy sure, just redraw the canvas to itself: draw image as-is, set filter property, set globalCompositeOperation to copy (in case there is alpha channel involved) and use drawImage with canvas as image source.

Comment: Okay, so it's so close, but is there a way to toggle the filter? I'm redrawing the image 3 times. The first time with no filter. The second time with a filter. When I copy and draw the canvas the third time, I want to draw it like the original image with no filter, but each time the filter stays to whatever I set it the second time. Canvas is so new to me...

Comment: @AlexKonetchy just disable the filter before drawing the last time by setting the property to "none" (see last line inside the onload handler). Also use the original image (img) as source for drawImage.

Comment: I can't, only because I draw a line on the image between the toggling.Setting the original image in drawImage() overwrites the lines that I drew.

Comment: @AlexKonetchy with canvas be prepared to redraw everything, that's just how it works. You need to keep track of all shapes, images, changes etc. and redraw all in the correct order when needed. (remember beginPath()).

Comment: Hmm, okay. Thank you!

Comment: any update about if this is now supported in all major browsers?